# angular unknown provider upload

Tags: angularjs, bower

I have a problem with upload module in Angular. I install module from https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload

**I use Angular 1.5.0**

In index.html i have:

```
 <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
```

My app.js

```
var app = angular
    .module('MyApp', [
        'ngAnimate',
        'ngCookies',
        'datatables',
        'ngResource',
        'ngRoute',
        'angularFileUpload',
        'ngSanitize',
        'ngTouch'
    ])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider...
```

This is my main.js

```
   angular.module('MyApp')
        .controller('MainCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope','$upload','$location', 'myService', function ($rootScope, $scope,$upload,$location, myService) {


        }]);
```

In console : `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uploadProvider <- $upload <- MainCtrl`

$upload variable is undefined

Please help me.

Comment: change $upload with 'FileUploader'. as mentioned in docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `$uploader` to `FileUploader`. there is some problem with fileuploader module, and updated FileUploader module using `FileUploader` service.

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('MyApp')
        .controller('MainCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope','FileUploader','$location', 'myService', function ($rootScope, $scope,FileUploader,$location, myService) {
         var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
        url: 'upload.php'
    });
     //Any other code or processing

        }]);
```

Wrong injector used please check above